# C# Pass Generic class obj to an Interface as param

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a question about genenic in C#, here is code:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void fun(ClassB b);
}
class ClassA: IMyInterface
{
    void IMyInterface.fun(ClassB b)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(a);
        b.fun();
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public void fun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("111");
    }
}
class ClassZ<T, K>
    where T: IMyInterface, new()
    where K: new()
{
    public T objT;
    public K objK;
    public void funB()
    {
        objT = new T();
        objK = new K();
        objT.fun(objK);    //Error, cannot convert from 'K' to 'ConsoleApp1.ClassB'
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassZ<ClassA, ClassB> objB = new ClassZ<ClassA, ClassB>();
        objB.funB();
    }
}
```

> cannot convert from 'K' to 'ConsoleApp1.ClassB'

T and K are all some class, I want invoke objT.fun(objK), objK as param.

Any suggustion? thanks!

Comment: What should happen in objK isn't of type `ClassB`?

Answer (score 2):

The method

```
void IMyInterface.fun(ClassB b)
```

expects a reference to an object of type `ClassB`. The `K` parameterized type does not guarantee this.

You could fix this by replacing the following generic constraint

```
where K: new()
```

with this one

```
where K: ClassB, new()
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because your interface *MyInterface* is expecting an object of type ClassB.
You can solve this by defining K as type of ClassB in ClassZ:

```
class ClassZ<T, K>
    where T: IMyInterface, new()
    where K: ClassB, new()
{
public T objT;
public K objK;
    public void funB()
    {
        objT = new T();
        objK = new K();
        objT.fun(objK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to let `K` constraint be `ClassB`

```
where K : ClassB,new()
```

instead of

```
where K : new()
```